# ImageView - change image and wait for layout to finish update

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, imageview

I am changing a image in an `ImageView` while already displaying the image. This COULD leed to a change of the layout as the image may be of a different size.

I draw some arrows/marks to special points on an image and animate them... My problem now is, that I need to wait for the `setImage...` function of the `ImageView` to finish so that I can calculate all necessary data under consideration of the new image...

- *first update of image*

On my first displayment of my view I wait with `ViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener` of my `ImageView` and calculate all points afterwards...

- *on following updates of the image (view is already visible)*

I don't know how to do it here...

**How can I wait for `setImage...` to finish drawing and only afterwards do my custom work?**

Answer (score 0):

Try listening to the `ImageView`'s layout change instead.

Call [`addOnLayoutChangeListener(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#addOnLayoutChangeListener(android.view.View.OnLayoutChangeListener)) on the `ImageView`.

You can recalculate the points every time `onLayoutChange...` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the solution and it was quite obvious...

Exactly for this reason, `view.post(...)` exists and this works quite good... This way, I don't need the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` at all...